# What is the purpose of downvoting community wikis?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I was browsing for a solution to download files from a link into Google Drive and came across [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/739527/573158), which is a community wiki, and has at the bottom of it the text

> EDIT: Please note that this answer dates from 2014, which is a long
>   time ago in computers. There is no point in downvoting if the
>   extension no longer works.

I had previously thought that the *purpose* of downvoting was to indicate that an answer does not work. However, this is my first time I consciously remember considering downvoting a community wiki, so I figured the rules might be different, so I should ask here.

Do community wikis have different conditions as to when one should downvote?

Answer (score 19):

No, there is no difference.

If the answer is wrong, doesn't work or whatever else in terms of not being helpful, it warrants a downvote.

Being set as community wiki, [or even being old](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/9378/old-posts-and-answers-need-protection), is not a guard against a downvote.

Comment: Furthermore, the notice itself should be removed from the answer, it is an inappropriate meta-commentary, that does not belong outside of the metacommunity (in my opinion).  *Worth pointing out the answer could be protected so nobody could upvote or downvote it.*

Comment: @Ramhound "Protected questions have the additional restriction that new users are not permitted to answer the question. Unlike locked questions, they can still be edited, commented on, and voted on. You can even vote to close them.

Comment: @DavidPostill - I could have sworn I have seen answers themselves protected, in such a way, where they could not be voted on.  However, I am aware of the difference between a closed question and a protected question.  I was just pointing out there was an alternative solution to prevents downvotes, to an answer that isn't accurate but still helpful.

Comment: @Ramhound You're thinking of Locked posts